# How to add column for total orders in customer grid in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid

I have added total number of orders column to customer grid in the magento admin.
I need to put 2 text box in that column like from and to so we can search customers whose total orders are between that given range.

ex. suppose we put 3 and 5 into (form and to) textbox then we will display all customers whose total orders are between 3 to 5.

```
and also need to work filtering (searching and sorting)
```

---

add code in the following file app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Grid.php

add this code in _prepareCollection() fucntion only

```
$sql ='SELECT COUNT(*)'
        . ' FROM ' . Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') . ' AS o'
        . ' WHERE o.customer_id = e.entity_id ';
        $expr = new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $sql . ')'); 

        $collection->getSelect()->from(null, array('orders_count'=>$expr));
```

---

and also add this code in _prepareColumns() function with same file

```
$this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Total Orders'),
            'align'     => 'left',
            'width'     => '40px',
            'index'     => 'orders_count',
            'type'  => 'number',
            'sortable' => true,
        ));
```

Comment: What is the datatype you used for `total number of orders` field?

Comment: 'type'  => 'number'

Comment: I think below answer helps you lot, Did you tried them?

Answer (score 1):

According to your Question asked, it seems like you have successfully added a Grand Total Column, you just need to add range boxes, that can help in filter.

Find the code below to add in customer Grid -

```
$this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Orders Count'),
            'width'     => '50px',
            'index'     => 'orders_count',
            'type'      => 'number',
        ));
```

**[EDITED]**

I have gone little bit deep in this Question and find that we can provide filter in the following manner -

```
$this->addColumn('orders_count', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Orders Count'),
            'align'     => 'left',
            'width'     => '40px',
            'index'     => 'orders_count',
            'type'  => 'number',
            'sortable' => true,
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterHasOrderTotalBetweenCallback'),
        ));
```

and add the following function -

```
public function _filterHasOrderTotalBetweenCallback($collection, $column){
```

`if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }
    if (!empty($value)) {
        $from = $value['from'];
        $to = $value['to'];           

        $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->having(
             "orders_count>=$from AND orders_count<=$to");
        Mage::log((string)$this->getCollection()->getSelect(),null,'customer.log');
    }        
    return $this;
}`

Adding the above function is providing the result in the form of query which is running fine in MYSQL , but not accepted in Magento

Comment: i already display total orders are placed by customers in the customer grid. now we need to put 2 text boxes in that column .we can search customers whose total orders are between that given range. ex. suppose we enter 3 and 5 into (form and to) text box then we will display customers whose total orders are between 3 to 5 in that customer grid. and also need to work on filtering

Comment: @sandip Baviskar, I have edited my answer please proceed with it

Answer (score -1):

you need to add `'type'  => 'number',` into your `Grid.php` file.  Example of customer_id:

```
    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID'),
        'width'     => '50px',
        'index'     => 'entity_id',
        'type'      => 'number',
    ));
```

Comment: i already display total orders are placed by customers in the customer grid. now we need to put 2 text boxes in that column .we can search customers whose total orders are between that given range.

ex. suppose we enter 3 and 5 into (form and to) text box then we will display customers whose total orders are between 3 to 5  in that customer grid. and also need to work on filtering